# fatal error: invalid function symbol table. runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to run my Golang app and I'm getting this error:

```
 runtime: pcHeader: magic= 0xfffffff1 pad1= 0 pad2= 0 minLC= 1 ptrSize= 8 pcHeader.textStart=                                            0x0 text= 0x103104340 pluginpath= 
 fatal error: invalid function symbol table
 runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized

 runtime stack:
 runtime.throw({0x10374b70f?, 0x7ff847918e88?})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x5d fp=0x7ff7bcdfef98 sp=0x7ff7bcdfef68           pc=0x10313789d
 runtime.moduledataverify1(0x0?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/symtab.go:627 +0x806 fp=0x7ff7bcdff098 sp=0x7ff7bcdfef98      pc=0x1031553e6
 runtime.moduledataverify(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/symtab.go:613
 runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:710 +0x3a fp=0x7ff7bcdff0f0 sp=0x7ff7bcdff098 pc=0x10313b2fa
 runtime.rt0_go()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:349 +0x11e fp=0x7ff7bcdff0f8 sp=0x7ff7bcdff0f0 pc=0x103167e9e
 exit status 2`
```

- I tried running "go run qlist" and got this error.
- I tried "go clean -cache"... didn't work
- I tried reinstalling go... didn't work
- I tried restarting my pc... didn't work

Comment: what is your go version and what is your GOPATH env var?

Comment: 1.20.5, $GOPATH appears to be empty

Comment: What is qlist? Build and execute the package separately so you can determine what exactly is crashing. This looks like memory corruption, but you haven’t shown any info about what you are running.

Comment: just my plist file editor..
it worked before but now i get this and i didnt change anything

Comment: when i run the build i get the same error
i also tried running my other app and i get the same error

Comment: You can use the `-x` flag to `go build` to see exactly what command is failing, maybe it’s even the `go` command itself. Is there any security software running which might be interfering?

Comment: i tried go run -x qlist:

https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ulubodusam.bash

Comment: So it’s not from building, it’s from executing `qlist` (stop using `go run` here, it’s just adding more things to try and sort through). Unless someone has seen this exact crash, there’s not much we can do without a [mre]

Comment: but it also happened when i tried running my other app
and i didnt change my code at all

Comment: Any ideas? I can't continue working on my app anymore

Comment: Searching for "fatal error: invalid function symbol table" doesn't yield many results, but perhaps this is helpful: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6245
; In your hastebin output, you can see the `-s` argument in the `link` tool invocation, that must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: But I’m not using -s

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
you can use this (Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.3.1 Release Candidate)

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=for%20Xcode

not use Command Line Tools for Xcode 15 version

Answer (score -1):

I say try these steps:

```
1. mkdir ~/new_go_path
2. export GOPATH=~/new_go_path
3. cd directory_with_go_code (should have go.mod)
4. rm go.sum
5. go mod tidy
6. go build
```

if that doesn't work, bi-sect the go.mod imports. i.e. remove half (and the references in the code) and see if error goes away. Then you know the problem import is in the other half.

Comment: tried it but still same error

Comment: oh i had small error, forgot = in export GOPATH

Comment: Yes I did it with the = but doesn’t work